# how to use install library in c++ in visual studio code?

Tags: c, scip

I want to use a library with c++ in visual  studio code with in Mac.  I installed scip and VScode but I can't use it.

when I run

```
1 error generated.
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I am not familiar with c but I know how to use scip's function. So I need to compile scip in c. any help ?

I installed scip in download file. and I have c/c++ Microsoft for visual studio code

Comment: Post the compiler command line you are using and relevant environment variables (INCLUDE, LIB, VS*, etc.).  Where did you install SCIP?  What compiler are you using?

Comment: I installed SCIP in my download

Comment: [Edit] your post, and provide all relevant information there.

Comment: @jwdonahue should I edited more?

Comment: Answer all questions.  Where did you get SCIP from?  What is the full path to wherever you "installed" it?  Did you run a setup program or just unpack a package?  Is it a source project/package or compiled libraries and header file?  Your compiler can't find the header files, so you have to configure your build environment so that it can.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up a few things here. Visual Studio Code cannot compile code - it's more like a fancy editor. You are probably referring to Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 or 2019. This is a fully-featured IDE that also comes with a C/C++ compiler.

To compile SCIP, I strongly recommend CMake. There are detailed instructions on how to do this in the [SCIP docs](https://scip.zib.de/doc-6.0.2/html/CMAKE.php).

Also keep in mind, that installation of SCIP is different from compiling it yourself. You need the sources and probably your self-built librarires/binaries to link SCIP to your own custom code. If you only want to *use* SCIP, then it's sufficient to run the installer and start it - no compilation whatsoever is necessary.

Comment: my problem is I so not know how to link skip to my code! is there any instructions link to help me?

Comment: You can check how the SCIP examples are built and try to replicate the code.